# "TypeError: heap argument must be a list" when process_data_events() is called on a RabbitMQ pika blocking connection

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

Before publishing a message, code checks that the RabbitMQ connection is not closed before doing the actual publish (see calling code below). However, it seems that some strange TypeError occurs when this check is done.

Further details:

- An async consumer (i.e. uses a select connection `pika.SelectConnection`) listens on a particular queue.
- When the consumer processes a message, it will publish other messages to another queue via a non-async producer (i.e. uses a blocking connection `pika.BlockingConnection`).
- Consumer and producer are separate pieces of code but lie in the same codebase and run in the same process (and thread) on the same server. They were separated for better code decoupling.
- The reason why only the consumer is async is because calling `rmq_consumer_connection.ioloop.start()` is a blocking operation (hence can't do the equivalent `rmq_producer_connection.ioloop.start()`). I may consider optimising (e.g. use separate threads for consumer and producer so both can be async) in the future.
- Using pika 0.12.0, RabbitMQ 3.7.8, Python 3.5

Stacktrace as follows:

```py
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]: job|callback_user_queue|ERROR| Exception in callback_user_queue(..)
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]:   File "/opt/app/gateway_messenger.py", line 282, in send_to_gateway
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]:     gv.rmq_producer_connection.process_data_events()
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]:   File "/home/prod/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 751, in process_data_events
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]:     with _IoloopTimerContext(time_limit, self._impl) as timer:
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]:   File "/home/prod/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 188, in __enter__
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]:     self._callback_result.signal_once)
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]:   File "/home/prod/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 112, in add_timeout
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]:     return self.ioloop.add_timeout(deadline, callback_method)
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]:   File "/home/prod/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 364, in add_timeout
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]:     return self._timer.call_later(deadline, callback_method)
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]:   File "/home/prod/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 199, in call_later
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]:     heapq.heappush(self._timeout_heap, timeout)
Apr 05 19:25:16 prod python[23326]: TypeError: heap argument must be a list
```

Calling code as follows:

```py
def send_to_gateway(uid, data):
...(non-relevant code)...
    try:
        gv.rmq_producer_connection.process_data_events() <-- fails here
    except pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        logger.warn("RMQ producer connection is closed. Re-opening...")
        initialise_producer()
...(non-relevant code)...


def initialise_producer():
    logger.info("Initialising RabbitMQ producer...")

    gv.rmq_producer_connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
        pika.ConnectionParameters(gv.config['rmq_ip']))
    gv.rmq_producer_channel = gv.rmq_producer_connection.channel()
    gv.rmq_producer_channel.queue_declare(queue=gv.config['rmq_queue'],
                                          durable=True)
    logger.info("Initialising RabbitMQ producer done!")
```

Expected result:

- During the check, if the RabbitMQ connection is closed, the producer will be re-initialised before the message is published.
- If connection is not closed, proceed to publish the message as per normal.

Comment: did you ever make any progress on this? I'm seeing the same issue in the same situation.

Comment: Upgrading to pika 1.0.0 and double-checking my code for thread safety helped solve the issue. I can't pinpoint the exact cause though.